Detecting text in binary blobs using ML
Context - I'm an experienced SWE with little expereince in ML, I would like to perform the following:
Given a binary blob (bytearray) of size 256, consisting of random bytes with meaningful text embedded, I would like to write a ML operation in Python that can detect said text.
So far I've used the following features/labels:

byte values / expected text
is byte utf8 / start/end positions of text in blob
number of bytes which are utf8 in N bytes before/after each byte / offset + text length

I've also tried several classifiers, including SVR and NNs, but result have been very disappointing. Any ideas would be welcome.
Sample blob with expected text of "translation NLP python"

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

In hex workshop it looks like this:


Is this definitely a ML classification problem? Have you tried simpler approaches? Perhaps translating the hexadecimal to text and using regular expressions?

@Jamie I'm not sure TBH, it seems heuristics might do a pretty good job, but as I said, I'm very inexperienced in the ML field, and it sounds to me like a problem which resembles digit recognition and therefore should be easily solved using ML techniques. In any case, this is what I am looking for ATM
